# Is there a way to ignore backslashes while migrating data to snowflake from SQL Server via ADF using snowflake linked service?

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The data in SQL server has backslashes in columns and when I try to copy it from sql server to snowflake via adf the backslashes escape the next ','(delimiting character) causing errors while loading. Is there a way to ignore the backslashes in ADF while doing this?

I am aware of the escape and escape_unenclosed_field format options but they don't seem to work when passed in ADF.
I tried using escape = "None" and escape_unenclosed_field = "None" in format options of sink side snowflake on adf. Also, tried using optionally enclosed by '"' but that did not help either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many columns have the backslashes? Can you use Data Flow to deal with the backslashe?

Comment: @LeonYue Hi, I can replace the backslashes in the query too, only problem is that it is part of data and we need them as they are in the table on snowflake as well.

Comment: Got it. Per my experience, I'm afraid we can't do that. Hope others can give more suggestions.

Comment: Can you try `SELECT REPLACE (YourField,'\','\\') FROM TABLE` to double escape the backslash and see if that works. You might need to refine it further to stop false positives.

Comment: Aug 2023 : Still facing this issue.. anyone found an elegant solution??

Thanks